# How to retrieve User's phone number from Twilio in Bot Framework?

Tags: sms, twilio, botframework

Have the bot working just fine via SMS. Now looking for the best way to retrieve the User's phone number being used in the SMS conversation.

Seems like it should be pretty straight forward (easy to do in a native Twilio app), but just not finding the example code or way to get at it from within the Bot Framework using the C# libraries.

I played a bit with the ChannelData off of Activity, but it's not there or I'm not using it correctly.

Any pointers to relevant documentation or sample code would be tremendously helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bot's Post handler receives a list of Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity when end users message the bot.  Each [Activity](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/d2f/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_activity.html) has a "From" [Channel Account](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dd/def/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_channel_account.html) that contains an "Id" and "Name".   You can find the Twilio phone number there.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!